# How do you make Text box expand if we stretch window with Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want that when I stretch the window, the text box within it also gets bigger.
I have been following a youtube video series from sentdex, so my code is somewhat similar to his.

I have tried to set it sticky, I have tried to put weight onto the columns and rows but it does not change.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import filedialog

class OpenFile(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"FileOpener")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save settings", 
                                    command= lambda:print("Doing nothing"))
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        tk.Tk.config(self,menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage,):

            frame =F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global filetextbox
        ### INPUT FRAME
        containerinput=tk.Frame(self)
        containerinput.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=4,sticky="nsew")
        containerinput.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        containerinput.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        ## Label
        labeltxt1 = tk.Text(self)
        labeltxt1.config(height=1,relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        #label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10,side=tk.LEFT)
        labeltxt1.grid(row=1,column=0)

        ## Text
        text1 = tk.Text(containerinput)
        text1.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill="both",expand=True)
        scroll1= tk.Scrollbar(containerinput,command=text1.yview)
        scroll1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.BOTH)
        text1.config(yscrollcommand=scroll1.set)       

        #containerinput.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill="both",expand=True)
        ##Button
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Choose file", 
                                command=lambda:getFile(self))
        #button1.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        button1.grid(row=0,column=0)

app=OpenFile()

app.mainloop()
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what kind of I want like:

[image]

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code.  It's hard to read at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first think you need to do to debug this is to temporarily give your frames distinctive colors. That makes it easy to see which of several nested frames are growing and which are not. It's also sometimes helpful to add extra padding so that you can see the inside edges of frames, but that's not necessary in this case.

So, start by giving colors to the different frames:

```
class OpenFile(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ...
        container = tk.Frame(self, background="pink")

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="blue")
        ...
        containerinput=tk.Frame(self, background="yellow")
```

When you do that, it becomes clear that the blue frame is expanding as you desire, but the yellow frame inside it is not expanding.

The reason is that you're putting the yellow frame (`containerinput`) inside your `StartPage` frame, but you aren't configuring it to resize. Since you added this with `grid`, you need to tell tkinter which rows and columns should get any extra unused space. You do this with `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` on the frame in which `containerinput` is placed. In this case that frame is `self`:

```
containerinput=tk.Frame(self, background="yellow")
containerinput.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=4,sticky="nsew")
...
self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Note: you still need to call `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` on `containerinput` since you are also placing widgets inside of that frame with `grid`.

Comment: Thank you for not only providing a solution, for also teaching an effective way to debug! Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You can bind '<Configure>' to catch all window resizes.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self)
    self.bind("<Configure>", self.update_size)
    ...

  def update_size(self, event):
    print(event.width, event.height) #this has all the information about the window resize
```

Source: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-window-size.htm

Comment: While what you wrote is true, it's not useful for solving this problem. Getting the window width and height doesn't change anything, and the correct solution to this problem doesn't need to know the width and height.

Comment: @BryanOakley you can manually update the width of the elements using element.config(width=...) This allows for more customization.

Comment: @pravymravec: while true, that still doesn't solve the problem, and only works under some circumstances (ie: the geometry manager may make the widget bigger or smaller than the requested width and height).